# Java treats Classes as Packages?

Tags: java

Directory tree:

```
App
|- src
     |- package S
        |- public class main.java
        |- public class U.java
     |- package C
```

U.java tree:

```
public class U
      |- public static class I
               |- public static func test
      |- public static class O
               |- public static func t
```

When I try to access `U.I.test()` on `main.java`. Javac gives following error:
`main.java:30: error: package U does not exist`.

java --version : `openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @Sweeper I edited the question so you can better understand

Comment: I need a set of steps that I can perform to reproduce the error "package U does not exist". Right now, you have given me the folder structure, but not what's in those files. What is in main.java and U.java?

Comment: @Sweeper `main.java` has only the main function. `U.java` has above tree, I try to access `U.I.test()`. where `I` is an inner class and `test` is a function in `class I` in main.java

Comment: Rather than describing the contents of the files, you should [edit] your question with the code that those files contain.

Comment: @Sweeper I did some edits

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Answer (score 1):

You can  try below code

```
  

    package S;
    
    public class main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        U outer=new U();
        U.I innerI=outer.new I();
        innerI.test();
    }
    }
```

Note: You can not directly access inner class method. If want to do so then you have to make your inner class and its method static and then call from main method as given below.

```
U.I.test();
```

Comment: Eclipse IDE gives me : Illegal enclosing instance specification for type U.I

Comment: I have edited the answer and putted complete code for class main